# suggestions for PDF topic location

Tags: java, pdf

Short version: Please give me a recommendation to the best place to post a question helping me convert a PDF to TEXT using JAVA programming.

Details: 
I've been working on trying to change a PDF to a text file using JAVA and keep the format as close to the PDF's as possible. I've currently been using a separate,free, third party program to do the converting and then the JAVA program I made does everything else I want. I've asked around a lot of places and most recommend PDFBox which didn't work. All PDFBox did was the same thing Adobe Read X would do, which is create a huge bunch of text mess. I've tried a lot of things and spent a lot of time on this. What I'm going to do now is share one of the PDF's I been trying convert and hopefully someone can help me with some JAVA code that will help convert this. I've only really got permission to share this old file once (even thou I'm 99% sure it would be fine to share the file a few other places) and I would like post the question at the most effect spot.

Comment: Your question seems to just be asking for recommendations: 1) for a Q&A site and 2) for an alternative to PDFBox.  Requests for recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: why not simply build a single executable or script that makes use of the existing programmes by calling them in the right order?

Comment: Hi Stefan Hegny - I've never tried that before. I will look into it as an option and see if I can figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't presenting your problem with your text extraction routine based on PDFBox as a stack overflow question be a good start?

Comment: I'm sorry mkl, I don't under stand what you mean when you say "text extraction routine based on PDFBox" I can say I don't think its a problem with PDFBox as I was able to get configured in my IDE just fine and use it; however, the results were the same as just clicking "save as" --> text on Adobe Reader X. Thank you for your contribution =)

Comment: @EricIp PDFBox text extraction has a sort option. Maybe try that one.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Ok thank you. I'll do a search for the sort option. If you have a link to direction or a small guide of some sort I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @EricIp If you use the ExtractText command line app, then use `-sort`. If you are using java, then call `stripper.setSortByPosition()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr this is something I have not tried, it has not been suggested to me, and I will look into this. Thank you!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Long story short, this looks very promising. I've made more progress from this then I have in a very long time and I feel like I might be able to work with this. Longer version of this story is, its taken some time for me to remember how to get PDFBox working again (because I gave up on it)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  and then there were issues with the code needing the lib's from 1.8 or so which is an older version and such. Right now the results are just showing up in my output box of the IDE, I need to get them into a .txt file so I can compare how it looks, BUT I can figure that all out by myself and this is looking promising. I didn't even end up having to share this file I really didn't want to share.

Comment: @EricIp glad to hear the good news! Please answer the question yourself if you think it can help others, or delete it, to avoid orphans :-)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I will but first I want to see this through and make sure works the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Well short version (and to actually answer my actual question) 
                   Answer is: http://stackoverflow.com

Special Thanks to @TilmanHausherr who went above and beyond by following my updates and helping me more.

```
                                Longer version.
```

I'm still having some formatting issues but I think I'll be able to find the rest on my own. As far as what I asked for getting the document formatted correctly using Java, that's done. As far as the question was asked this document is kind of formatted correctly it just doesn't look as pretty as some other things I've used.

After that, I got stuck because the formatting would not be correct after the conversation. I've asked around before and most said it would be too hard to explain. In the end I've had to re-learn how to attach PDFBox, trouble shoot through common problems others have had, and a single line of code from TilmanHausherr as shown in the comments helped.

When I started this project I had to learn how to get PDFBox to work with my IDE and how to arrange libs. and such. I then went on to find some old googled codes that used PDFBox to convert text from a PDF. I can't share the code used to do the converting but it takes about 4 to 5 mins to search for the original posters work. There still some modifications I had to do to their code just to get it to work, but I just followed prompts from my IDE: Eclipse.

I used this code to write to the text file instead of a Formatter.:

```
String textFromMain  =  textForAll; 
try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "text.txt" )  ) {
    out.println( textFromMain );
}
```